# Generate Hibernate Id from database function, for table partitioning

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, partitioning

I want to embed date information in the primary key, for a table that will be partitioned (monthly) in a PostgreSQL database. This should in theory speed up the process on finding out in which partition to look for the data. I followed [this article](https://database.one/blog/date_in_sequence) to embed the date in a date into the serial.
Now, I am however facing the problem that I can't get the Id been used by Hibernate.

c.f. the sql that should give an idea of the attempted approach.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_serial START 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_test_key() RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
DECLARE
    new_id bigint;
BEGIN
    new_id = (nextval('public.test_serial'::regclass)::bigint % 10000000000000::bigint
        + ( (EXTRACT(year from now())-2000)::bigint * 10000::bigint
            + EXTRACT(month from now())::bigint * 100::bigint
            + EXTRACT(day from now())::bigint
              )::bigint * 10000000000000::bigint
        )::bigint;
    RETURN new_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE test
( id bigint primary key default gen_test_key(),
  something text,
  tstamp timestamp default now()
) PARTITION BY RANGE (id);

CREATE TABLE test_2022_10 PARTITION OF test
FOR VALUES FROM (2210100000000000000::bigint ) TO (2211010000000000000::bigint);
```

I came across [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479912/hibernate-generate-id-from-database-function), where it was suggested to use a stored procedure. Unfortunately only functions are allowed as default in the table definition and therefore stored procedures, seam not to work for me.

Comment: I think you can call function like stored procedure https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-jdbc/call-postgresql-stored-function/

Comment: Why do you think your queries would be faster? This article doesn't even show it. A WHERE condition using the timestamp is good enough to go to the right partition(-s)

Comment: @Frank There is a lot of existing queries that would have to be rewritten to include the timestamp, that's why we're experiementing with that solution. In part 2 of the blog post you can see some numbers regarding performance https://database.one/blog/date_in_sequence_updates

Comment: @Felix: There is not a single SELECT statement, nor query plan, that proves anything. There is a test on the INSERT statements, without any concurrency. I would be a little worried about setval() in a concurrent environment.

Comment: Can't you just create a new partition e.g. every day based on the current sequence value? That would approximate pretty good and you don't have to change anything in your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need here is a subtype of `SequenceStyleGenerator` that overrides `determineBulkInsertionIdentifierGenerationSelectFragment` to run the code of this function. You should be able to configure this generator on your entity with `@GenericGenerator`. I understand the desire to use this concept when you don't want to change your existing queries, but are you sure that partitioning will help you in your use case?

Also, be careful and do not rely on the date information in the primary key, because with pooled optimizers, it might happen that a value is generated way before it actually is used as primary key for a row.

Comment: it's a good point to watch out for the pooled-optimisers! I will set them to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred=none` to hopefully avoid trouble there!  I did only find one article that described the behaviour of the optimisers though https://lumme.dev/2022/04/03/hibernate-table-generator-optimizers.html . Any additional resources that you could point me to?

Comment: Just set the allocationSize to 1. What about my other comment? Can't you just create a new partition e.g. every day based on the current sequence value? That would approximate pretty good and you don't have to change anything in your existing code.

Comment: Yes, I do like the idea of creating a new partition daily! I saw that `pg_partman` could help to automate that partition creation process. Which would also make this, a database-internal step and avoid relying on some externally scheduled `CREATE` to be sent. I will definitely investigate if that solution is possible, given Amazon RDS and some manual UNIQUE INDEXES that need to be created for each new partition.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a solution that worked out in the end as suggested @ChristianBeikov here the entity with the annotations pointing to the `CustomIdGenerator`.

```
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "CustomIdGenerator", strategy = "nl.test.components.CustomIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CustomIdGenerator")
    private Long id;

    private String something;
    private OffsetDateTime tstamp;
}
```

As explained by @Mr_Thorynque [it is similarly possible to call a stored function as a procedure](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-jdbc/call-postgresql-stored-function/). Just replace `"CALL gen_test_key()"` with `"SELECT gen_test_key()"` and don't pass it to the wrong method for stored procedures `connection.prepareCall(CALL_STORE_PROC);`, but instead `connection.prepareStatement(STORED_FUNCTION);` So, this is the `CustomIdGenerator`.

```
public class CustomIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

private static final String STORED_FUNCTION = "select gen_test_key()";

@Override
public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
    Long result = null;
    try {
        Connection connection = session.connection();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(STORED_FUNCTION);
        ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            result = resultSet.getLong(1);
            System.out.println("Generated Id: " + result);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        throw new HibernateException(sqlException);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```